# Python XLRD module gives ValueError for some ASCII characters

Tags: python, ascii, xlrd

I'm trying to read some data from an excel file using `xlrd` in python. There are some cells containing special characters like sigma, Pi, etc.; but `xlrd` gives me `UnicodeEncodeError`.

This is my excel file:

[image]

This is the code I use:

```
import xlrd
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx')
    s = wb.sheet_by_name('test')
    for row in range(1, s.nrows):
        values = {}
        for column in range(s.ncols):
            values.update({s.cell(0, column).value: str(s.cell(row, column).value)})    
            print values
```

And this is the output:

```
{u'formula': 'a + b * 15', u'name': 'test1'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\testXLRD.py", line 21, in <module>
    values.update({s.cell(0, column).value: str(s.cell(row, column).value)})
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2211' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What should I do??

Comment: My guess: You are casting the value to `str()`. Python uses ascii (default) to decode the string. What is the return value of `s.cell(row, column).value`??

Comment: Please check out the comment I left for Sebastien's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mathias said, the `str()` cast is failing because it's trying to decode in ascii a unicode string `u'\u2211'` whereas it should use for instance 'utf-8'.

Since `s.cell(row, column)` returns [a float, an int or some unicode string](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Cell-class), you'd better to either don't change the format or convert everything in unicode while you're manipulating it:

```
values.update({s.cell(0, column).value: unicode(s.cell(row, column).value)})
```

If you really want a string, and not unicode, this should work:

```
values.update({s.cell(0, column).value: unicode(s.cell(row, column).value).encode('utf-8')})
```

Comment: This is the output for second row: `{u'formula': u'\u2211 (ai)', u'name': u'test2'}`. I don't want it. I want the actual "Sigma" character.

Comment: `u'\u2211 (ai)'` is exactly the character you want, it's just stored as unicode. Try `print u'\u2211 (ai)'` for instance. If you want to store `string` and not `unicode` in your dict, you can use the second formulation, but usually you prefer to work with unicode and only convert them for the output.

Comment: The second solution gives me this: `{u'formula': '\xe2\x88\x91 (ai)', u'name': 'test2'}`. I repeat, I actually want the Sigma sign.

Comment: Here again, `\xe2\x88\x91` is exactly the symbol that you want, but encoded in utf-8. Try to `print your_dict['formula]` to convince yourself. How do you output this result? The thing is that you just print the dict directly, Python will not convert the encoded string to the symbol and will leave `'\xe2\x88\x91 (ai)'`, but it's actually the symbol that you want.